# Any downside to 'redundant' clustering column?

Tags: cassandra, cql

I've noticed that changing a regular Cassandra column to a clustering column can significantly reduce the size of the table in some circumstances.

For this example table:

```
id     UUID        K
time   TIMESTAMP   C
state  TINYINT    (C)
value  DOUBLE
```

The size of 100000 rows is estimated at 3.9 MB if `state` is an ordinary column, or 2.4 MB if `state` is a clustering column (estimated using the method in [DataStax course DS220](https://academy.datastax.com/courses/ds220-data-modeling/physical-partition-size)).

If you look at how the data is physically stored it isn't hard to see why this difference exists. In the former case there are two internal cells per timestamp - one for `state` and one for `value`. In the latter case `value` is incorporated into the cell key so there is just one cell per timestamp, and the timestamp (part of the cell key) is stored only once.

The second clustering column does not create any new restrictions on what can be queried. `SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=? AND time>=? AND time<?` is still fine.

It seems like a win-win situation. Are there any downsides, in particular, performance-wise?

(All I can think of is that if `state` is a regular column then it can be omitted from an INSERT and the `state` internal cell will never be created. I imagine if `state` is a regular column and *usually* omitted then the table will be very slightly smaller than if `state` is a clustering column.)

---

**Additional comments**
It's worth noting that in the definition above you can't filter by `state` without an equality filter on `time`, making it not very useful for filtering `state`. And if you put the `state` column above `time` to resolve this then yes you can filter by `state` and `time` inequality, but if you want all states (IN clause) then the rows are returned ordered by `state` first, then `time`, which again is not very useful.

Answer (score 1):

I would think the main difference here is that if it's a clustering column it must be provided with INSERTs as it's part of the primary key. Also, as it's part of the primary key, you can't update it either, which could be problematic for some tables. If you don't have any concerns about either of those two, I don't see any reason why you couldn't add it.

Answer (score 1):

1) You create a row per `state`. Your data model would have to realize and understand that. You could potentially create two rows with the different `state`s for the same `id`, `time`, which the original model disallows.

2) If you delete, you'll either need to specify `state` or you'll be creating `Range Tombstones` (range deletes, because you're deleting all rows for a given `id` and `time`, but it may be a range of `state`s). Range tombstones are especially expensive (on the read path) in 2.1, and aren't properly accounted for in `TombstoneOverwhelming` exception handlers until a fairly recent version of Cassandra, so avoiding range tombstones is usually a good idea, unless you actually need them.